# How to use input type date in ref?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, input, vuejs3

I can hide `input type file` and trigger it from another element like so:

```
<button @click="$refs.fileRef.click()"></button>
<input type="file" ref="fileRef" style="display: none">
```

but when I try that with `input type date` it doesn't work:

```
<button @click="$refs.dateRef.click()"></button>
<input type="date" ref="dateRef" style="display: none">
```

Any way I can activate the `date picker` via `ref`?

Comment: Try to trigger `focus()` instead of `click()`

Comment: @Romalex This only focuses the `input field` of the `date` but doesn't activate its `date picker` component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do `$refs.dateRef.showPicker()`:

```html
<button @click="$refs.dateRef.showPicker()"></button>
<input type="date" ref="dateRef" style="display: none">
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct approach, `v-model` is working with. Thank you

Comment: Are you using script setup syntax?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `script setup`.

Comment: Please check this 
 https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNpVUNFuwjAM/BUrL4A00veuoE3aB0x79gt06QhrnSh2QKjqv89pYRJvse/Od7nRvMdoL9mZ2jTcJh8F2EmOeyQ/xJAERkiugwm6FAZYKXWF1AZige+DuC/FdoWx3rwidZla8YGAT+H6ofCnb39dWm9GJHjw7eXQZ2cL5QEDANKE1FRLBnVvxA2xV4W+AZpjFtG7b22vkh2aZwM0+7KYHSDOq6ZaJEXeeIpZQG7RqbSQ0JTM90Ez6cxy62fYs/reagqktJKk+o9iXszSynY4RHvmQNrb/De8A4ymhnlTdtpWmdGcRCLXVcVdW9o+sw3pp9KXTZnED846HrbHFK7skh5GU05oI5OZ/gBOt5PV

Answer (score 1):

a solution seems to force display the picker on click with `onclick="this.showPicker()"`

```
  <button @click="$refs.fileRef.click()">file</button>
  <input type="file" ref="fileRef" style="display: none">


  <button @click="$refs.dateRef.click()">date</button>
  <input type="date" ref="dateRef" style="display: none" onclick="this.showPicker()">
```

but as say in the doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/showPicker
if you try call in a frame you will have a security exception

> Note: Pickers for date, datetime-local, month, time, week are launched
> in the same way. They cannot be shown here because live examples run
> in a cross-origin frame, and would cause a SecurityError

Comment: While this shows the `date picker`, it seems that it creates a conflict with `v-model`, since it's not working anymore with the input field.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `showPicker()` method to activate the date picker on button click.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="$refs.dateRef.click()">Click Me!</button>
  <input type="date" ref="dateRef" style="display: none" onclick="showPicker()"/>
</div>
```

In above code snippet, I am getting cross-domain security error which is also mentioned [here](https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/16582). Can you please give a try in your project.